# Can I sort the tabs in Eclipse alphabetically?

Tags: eclipse, usability

Just a quick question:

I'm using a lots of tabs in Eclipse and I wonder if there is a way to have them sorted alphabetically. Is there a settings I'm missing for years or a plugin that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I keep wondering why such comprehensive IDE like Eclipse lacks simple and common features like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, but you can "Switch to Editor" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)

And then sort by name:

[image: http://img709.i_mageshack.us/img709/3233/eclipseswitcheditor.png]

Comment: Ah, I always forget about that shortcut! Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 12):

Apparently there is a behavior called MRU which does this sorting. To enable it (in Juno at least) go to Window->Preferences->General->Appearance and set the theme to "Classic" or "Windows 7 Classic".

Answer (score 2):

The plugin *Extended VS Presentation plugin for Eclipse* supports
tab ordering

see 
http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html

Comment: Sadly that plugin doesn't seem to work with any of the 4.x versions.