# How to alphabetically sort tabs in new versions of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I sort the tabs in Eclipse alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613060/can-i-sort-the-tabs-in-eclipse-alphabetically)

Is there a way to alphabetically sort open tabs (editors) in Eclipse in the drop-down chevron? I seem to remember doing it in an older version of Eclipse, but can't seem to figure it out in Juno.

Comment: This might answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613060/can-i-sort-the-tabs-in-eclipse-alphabetically?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, that post seemed kind of old though. Was curious if they added it. I'm almost sure I was able to do it in the last version of Eclipse I was using around 6 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

I already had the **[Extended VS Plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/eclipse/)** installed and wanted to share some screen shots of it since it does what you asked about.

After installing the plugin, you must enable it like so :

```
First time after plugin installation please enable Extended VS Presentation under:    
Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Current presentation.
```

Then you can sort the tabs either on-demand by right-clicking on one of the tabs like so:
[image]

OR, you can choose to have the tabs automatically sorted by going into `Preferences -> Appearance -> Extended VS Presentation` like so :

[image]

I had originally installed this for it's `Session Save` feature, which allows you to easily save the list of Open Editor Tabs as sessions which can be restored later. Uber useful if you have opened a number of files related to a task or a bug and need to refer to them later.